How to parse SIWE on chain?
I have a complex nested struct which contains a field capabilites:
capabilities: [{
    "sig": "0xef8f88fb285c0065946f7257034209923e3bbf7c6c69f8863be213e50a1c1d7f18124eefdc595b4f50a0e242e8e132c5078dc3c52bda55376ba314e08da862e21a",
    "derivedVia": "web3.eth.personal.sign",
    "signedMessage": "localhost:3000 wants you to sign in with your Ethereum account:
        0x5259E44670053491E7b4FF9A120C70be1eAD646b


        URI: session:6a1f1e8a00b61867b85eaf329d6fdf855220ac3e32f44ec13e4db0dd303dqa6a
        Version: 1
        Chain ID: 1
        Nonce: 0xfe88c94d760f01a17f961bf4bdfb6e0c6cd10d3fda5cc861e805ca1240c58553
        Issued At: 2023-10-30T08:25:33.371Z
        Expiration Time: 203-11-06T08:25:33.348Z
        Resources:
        - urn:recap:eyJldHQiOnsibGl0LWFjY2Vzc2NvbnRyb2xjb25kaXRpb246Ly81MjRhNjk3YTQxMGE0MTdmYjk1YTlmNTJkNTdjYmE1ZmE3Yzg3YjNhY2QzYjQwOGNmMTQ1NjBmYTUyNjkxMjUxIjp7IiovKiI6W3t9XX19LCJwcmYiOltdfQo=",
    "address":"0x5259E44670053491E7b4FF9A120C70be1eAD646b"
}],

It is an array of SIWE (Sign In With Ethereum) messages. signedMessage is always in the SIWE format. I want to extract the URI field: session:6a1f1e8a00b61867b85eaf329d6fdf855220ac3e32f44ec13e4db0dd303dqa6a. How can I do that?
I was wondering whether there is a package that helps in easy extraction of SIWE fields? Or is a way of using Chain Agnostic CApability Object (CACAO) here like converting SIWE to CACAO and process CACAO on-chain?

Do you just want to extract the value of URI field of all the SIWE messages from the capabilities array using JS ?

No have to do it on chain as we need to validate that the user message isn't tampered. I also have to use erecover to verify the integrity of the user message

As you've mentioned "The intermediary explicitly passes the user message as we need to verify its integrity on-chain", so are you getting the capabilities array i.e., an array of struct as a parameter to your solidity function?

The intermediary receives the tire message including the capabilities  array

SIWE is EIP-191 message.
EIP-191 is not meant for on-chain parsing, because I am pretty sure the actual message does not get delivered on-chain, only message hash, but I could be wrong here.

The intermediary explicitly passes the user message as we need to verify its integrity on-chain
